# How to make a split screen with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have been trying very hard to make a split screen using Bootstrap. Here's what it looks like when I managed to do it with CSS:

[image: 1]

But I need to make it responsive to mobile users so I'm remaking it with Bootstrap. However the image and textbox don't resize for some reason.

By responsive I mean that it should become single row with 2 columns and vice versa depending wether you're on a desktop or mobile.

Edit: Sorry for this sudden change, but I'm now using Bootstap ver5.

```css
#promotion-textbox {
  top: 115px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  left: 55%;
  background-color: white;
  object-fit: fill;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#promotion-title {
  padding: 10px;
  position: static;
  color: #23272a;
  font-size: 3vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

#promotion-button {
  width: 40vw;
  opacity: 0.8;
  left: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 620px;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <!-- First Half -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  </div>
  
  <!-- Second Half -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="promotion-textbox">
      <div id="promotion-title">
        Duck Zone is the best game of all time, I mean just look at these awesome reviews:<br /><br /> TheP0mp21 Says:<br />- Game is pretty good but it needs a your mum duck that is extremely fat and spawns other ducks.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "don't resize"? What does "responsive to mobile users" mean? Please revise to be more clear about your desired behavior. Note that you've applied some heavy-handed CSS positioning rules that tend to conflict with Bootstrap and with responsive behavior in general. You can probably achieve your goal with virtually none using the tools that Bootstrap provides, but you need to tell us what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, if you are using a library then take advantage of it, use its [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/), and learn its [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):

- Add `vh-100` utility class to your `row`
- Add `w-100 h-100` in `img` tag HTML and in CSS add `object-fit: cover`

Because you've updated your question from [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) to [ootstrap-5](/questions/tagged/ootstrap-5), to remove the spacing in order to hide the horizontal scrollbar you need to replace `no-gutters` to `g-0`

**Note:** You have a lot of styles that doesn't make sense, such `left/top` without `position`

I also I've improved your code

```css
#promotion-textbox {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#promotion-title {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #23272a;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

#promotion-button {
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: transparent;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover
}

.col-6:last-child {
  background: darkgray
}

.promotion-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row g-0 vh-100">
  <!-- First Half -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="img w-100 h-100" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  </div>
  <!-- Second Half -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="promotion-column">
      <div id="promotion-textbox">
        <div id="promotion-title">
          Duck Zone is the best game of all time, I mean just look at these awesome reviews:<br /><br /> TheP0mp21 Says:<br />- Game is pretty good but it needs a your mum duck that is extremely fat and spawns other ducks.
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="promotion-button">All Projects</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this is great, thanks! The only issues are still that it enables scrolling and neither the image or textbox are centered. Also the "All Projects" thing is a button which is why I used <input>. But yeah I'm not that great at CSS

Comment: Did you check my snippet? there is no scrolling, take a look, I just edited. AS for the button, Is that a link or a load more action ?, if is a load more, then use `button type="button"`

Comment: @Tim_M look at my updated answer, because you changed from bootstrap 4 to 5

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting in so much effort. There are only 2 issues, when the window is big enough the image starts to overflow and overlay everything under, and the fact that it's not responsive to mobile users (it should become one column).

Comment: You really need to be CLEAR in your requirements,  to  have one column in mobile just redo `col-6` to `col-md-6`, as your question look like you wanted always 2 columns. Regarding overflowing everything under below,  you need to update your snippet with that code so I can give a fix  for that

Comment: Sorry, I thought saying "By responsive I mean that it should become single row with 2 columns and vice versa depending wether you're on a desktop or mobile." in the main post was clear enough. And for the overflow when I had made this in CSS all of the stuff below the image would simply move down as the image grew vertically, and the textbox moved down so that it would stay centered.

Comment: can't understand the issue still

Comment: Sorry for not respoding earlier, here's an image I made that showcases the overlay problem: https://imgur.com/a/4LzoFPc

Comment: remove `vh-100`

Answer (score 0):

You must use responsive image if you want it to be responsive. I also removed gutters from the row.

EDIT: made some improvment, `height:100vh` is really helpful. Takes exactly the height of the window.

```css
.half {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.my-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#promotion-textbox {
  top: 115px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  object-fit: fill;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#promotion-title {
  padding: 10px;
  position: static;
  color: #23272a;
  font-size: 3vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

#promotion-button {
  width: 40vw;
  opacity: 0.8;
  left: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 620px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <!-- First Half -->
  <div class="half col-sm-6">
    <img class="img my-image" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
  </div>
  <!-- Second Half -->
  <div class="half col-sm-6">
    <div id="promotion-textbox">
      <div id="promotion-title">
        Duck Zone is the best game of all time, I mean just look at these awesome reviews:<br /><br /> TheP0mp21 Says:<br />- Game is pretty good but it needs a your mum duck that is extremely fat and spawns other ducks.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
<p>content </p>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! There are only 2 problems: neither the image or textbox are centered (justify-content:center does nothing) and you can scroll horizontally which I don't want. (I'm sure it can be fixed with overflow: hidden but I think it's better to prevent it from overflowing at all.)

Comment: The image is centered. As for the rest I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

To make a split screen (two columns) use .row as parent and .col-md-6 for children. "md" part means that columns will expand to full screen width on medium and smaller screens( you can choose: xxl, xl, lg, md, sm, xs). TO make it fit the screen vertically add min-height: 100vh; for both columns and media query for the break point with min-height: 50vh;

source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/

Bootstrap 4 example (works in bootstrap 5 and 4):

CSS:

```
.img-col{
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  
}
.min-h-50{
  min-height:100vh;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .min-h-50{
    min-height:50vh;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 img-col min-h-50">
      
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 bg-dark min-h-50">
    <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
      <div class="col-10 align-self-center">
        <div class="bg-white p-3">rff</div>
        <div class="mt-3 text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary">xxx</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```